# add data by state and display total of each state in java

Tags: java, database, addition

I have data set as below:

```
State    Value
CA     10
CA     20
CA     30
NE     10
NE     15
NE     20
AK     20
AK     40
AK     50
```

I have to add value of each state and have to display total of each state.
output as shown below:

```
CA     60
NE     45
AK     110
```

can any one guide me the code to do it in java

Comment: What do you mean with a *dataset*? An (SQL) database?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score -1):

You need a data structure that supports a Key/Value pair, like a hashtable or dictionary.  The algorithm is simple, check for the existence of the key, if it exists, get the value, add the new value and then store the new value for that key, otherwise create a new entry for the key and store the current value.